# how shall i form the connection string for azure event hub without any shared key

Tags: python, azure, primary-key, azure-eventhub

how shall i form the connection string for azure event hub without any shared key. I do have a primary key. I am using python to do the task. any help on forming connection string using only primary key will be appreciable

Comment: Can you help me understand what you mean by "without any shared key" and "primary key?"  I want to be sure that we're using the same terminology.    What is it that you're looking to use for authorization?

Answer (score 1):

The connection string for Azure Event Hub is in the format designed by azure:

`Endpoint=sb://{EventHubNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={PolicyName};SharedAccessKey={Key};EntityPath={EventHub}`

You could find it in the portal, navigate to your Event Hub -> Shared Access Policies. The primary key is a part(as SharedAccessKey) of the connection string.

[image]